# Location Marker Not Displaying Swift 4

Tags: ios, swift, mkmapview, swift4, mkuserlocation

I am trying to display the current location of the user and have the region set to their current location.

Here is my code.

```
    @IBOutlet weak var mapView: MKMapView!

    var locationManager = CLLocationManager()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        self.locationManager.requestWhenInUseAuthorization()

        if CLLocationManager.locationServicesEnabled() {

            locationManager.delegate = self
            locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyNearestTenMeters
            locationManager.startUpdatingLocation()

        }
    }

    func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didUpdateLocations locations: [CLLocation]) {

        let locValue:CLLocationCoordinate2D = manager.location!.coordinate
        print("locations = \(locValue.latitude) \(locValue.longitude)")
        let userLocation = locations.last
        let viewRegion = MKCoordinateRegionMakeWithDistance((userLocation?.coordinate)!, 600, 600)
        self.mapView.setRegion(viewRegion, animated: true)
    }
```

**What happens:**

1. Map loads
2. Map region is set to current location
3. Map region will keep updating to the current location
4. Current location gets printed to the console

**What doesn't work:**

1. "Blue" current location indicator does not appear.

If you know what I need to do to make the "Blue" current location indicator appear it will be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to set

```
mapView.showsUserLocation = true
```

In `viewDidLoad`